# Error "Not a Function" in javascript accesing a module function in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working with a company with large angular infrastructure and here I have spent two days in a task labeled as : "Add new link on menu".

As I said, I have to "add a link" in a menu, but that link must to open a new window with a particular page in a particular environment (think like: open a page with the history of debts of the particular client we were watching)

To call this page, I need to make a post to a particular ActionBean (don't ask why. I don't know. The legacy code is huge and I'm a simple soldier without decision power). After a lot of struggle I could figure it that the company have a library in AngularJs to create this "post" request. A simplification of the definitions will be:

```
angular.module('myApp.formBuilder', []).factory('myAppFormBuilder', ['MyAppPleaseWaitModal', function (myAppPleaseWaitModal) {
                            function FormBuilder(url, method) {
                                this.$form = $('<form />').prop({
                                    action: url,
                                    method: method || 'post'
                                });
                            }
            FormBuilder.prototype.add = function (name, value) { .. }
            FormBuilder.prototype.submit = function () { .. }
            return {
                    /**
                     * Creates a new builder
                     * 
                     * @param url
                     * @param [method]
                     * @return {FormBuilder}
                     */
                    create: function (url, method) {
                        return new FormBuilder(url, method);
                    }
                };
```

And the way this is used (based on previous code in other pages)

```
define(['angular', 'lodash'], function (angular, _) {
    var module = angular.module('somethingController', ['myapp.formBuilder']);

    module.controller('SomethingController', ['$scope', '$timeout',  'myappPleaseWaitModal', 'myappFormBuilder', 
                                                    function ($scope, $timeout, myappFormBuilder) {
   
        
        $scope.goToDamnPage = function () {
            myappFormBuilder
               .create(CONTEXT_PATH + "/app/ClientOverview.action")
               .add('id', $scope.client.Id)
               .target("_blank")
               .submit();
            };
            
   
         // other stuff
       
       
    }]);
```

And finally, the view have this

```
<li> <a  href="javascript:void(0)" id="goToDamnPageBtn"  ng-click="goToDamnPage()" >Damn Page<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span></a></li>
```

When I click on the link, I receive an ugly error: Error: myappFormBuilder.create is not a function

And a pointer to the following line on angular.js

[image]
I suspect that I need some reference, because clearly doesn't know that myappFormBuilder.create returns an function, but I could haven't figure it which one. I suspect is something silly that any angular developer with experiencies can spot instantly... sadly, I'm too new to this technology

My Best regards and thankns in advance

Comment: Please look at the answer if that helps @nisanio

Answer (score 0):

You need to include **myappPleaseWaitModal** in your function as you have already passed it in the array in controller definition in the same sequence.

This will solve the problem:

```
module.controller('SomethingController', ['$scope', '$timeout',  'myappPleaseWaitModal', 'myappFormBuilder', 
    function ($scope, $timeout,myappPleaseWaitModal, myappFormBuilder) {


}]);
```

**Reason:** When you mention a particular sequence of dependencies in your array while defining a controller, angular expects you to have the same sequence in the controller function too.

Since in your case the sequence was not correct, angular was taking 'myappFormBuilder' to be 'myappPleaseWaitModal'.

Thats the reason it said **its not a function.**

Answer (score 0):

You didnt declaring 'myappPleaseWaitModal' in your controller function

```
module.controller('SomethingController', ['$scope', '$timeout',  'myappPleaseWaitModal', 'myappFormBuilder', 
                                                function ($scope, $timeout, myappPleaseWaitModal,myappFormBuilder) {
```

use this

instead of

```
  module.controller('SomethingController', ['$scope', '$timeout',  'myappPleaseWaitModal', 'myappFormBuilder', 
                                                    function ($scope, $timeout, myappFormBuilder) {
```